# No crea conexión en CURL tipo GET

Tags: php, curl

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando hacer una conexión con CURL pero no logro obtener una respuesta de echo no me esta marcando ni error. Antes de hacer la conexión en CURL simule la conexión con Postman el cual si me está regresando una respuesta.

A continuación, les anexo mi simulación con Postman y mi código en CURL:

> Conexión Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Código CURL

```
function get_zoho(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Accounts/540170000002456663";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.83b0845ee6e393418524e28850fd21e4.df05d9745105b96c297b05231e27fgtd"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($data);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

No crea conexión en CURL y no me devuelve nada como respuesta.

Comment: Te falta `:` después del nombre del encabezado: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Zoho-oauthtoken: 1000.83b0845ee6e393418524e28850fd21e4.df05d9745105b96c297b05231e27fgtd");`

Comment: En el Postman no coloque los ":" y si me devolvio respuesta, tambein ya lo hice con los ":" y aun sigue sin traerme nada.

Comment: De echo si le pongo ":" a la simulación en postman no me trae nada

Comment: Asumo que los otros 7 encabezados que tienes ocultos ya los incluiste en curl, principalmente el de tipo de contenido.

Comment: Yo solo agregue el dato de Zoho-oauthtoken con su valor, la URL y fue todo lo que le movi

Comment: no, no me manda ni error ni respuesta. Hice una pericion con Post y si me quedo, ahora necesito esta tipo Get pero no me devuelve nada pero en el Postan si devuelve.

Comment: Pon un control de errores para ver por qué podría estar fallando: `if(curl_errno($ch))
  {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }`

Comment: En Postman haz click en `Code` y selecciona `PHP cURL`

Comment: Muchas gracias ya quedo, enseguida pongo la respuesta.